# CSRF token mismatch exception in ajax post request in laravel 5.3 on localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, csrf-protection

I am newbie to laravel. I am using laravel 5.3 on localhost and i am posting data to controller function using ajax post request. I have integrated the CSRF token like this
inside the head section of master template

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

The after including jquery i add this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }

      });
      console.log($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    });
  </script>
```

i am sending data on button click like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './add_to_cart',
    data: {id:prod_id,name: name,price:price},
    success: function( msg ) {

    }
});
```

the first call goes right ,no error. But after the first call each call return error

TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

Here is the error screenshot:
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully reviewing my code .I found this piece of code was doing this.
Session::flush(); after removing this issue solved.
Thanks all for their effort specially @Naveen Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Call the ajax function with headers included not separately. 
I believe your meta tag is like this

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/add_to_cart',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    data: {id:prod_id,name: name,price:price},
    success: function( msg ) {

    }
});
```

So each time when the ajax call is done, Header will contain `csrf_token()`.

Comment: Thanks naveen for reply.I have included meta tag same as you described. I have tried your solution but still the same error.First call give no error but after that it throws the exception.

Comment: Also i have checked the headers and with each request it contains the csrf token but still dont  know what is the problem

Comment: Can you check if `/add_to_cart` route has `api` or `web` middleware. If it's web that might be an issue as token will change with every POST request. Change it to `api`. WIth Laravel 5.3 make sure the route is in `routes/api.php` file.

Comment: All default routes should be in web.php expect api routes. @ChrisCynarski. There is no need for him to change unless he is creating api

Comment: @Chris Cynarski i am not creating api ,i am working on web.

Comment: are you appeding /add_to_cart to the existing url ? or /add_to_cart is a route ?

Comment: @Naveen Kumar Route::post('/add_to_cart', 'HomeController@add_to_cart');

Comment: check my edited answer. You shouldn't add **.** before route in your ajax url

Comment: @Naveen Kumar changed url to this url: '/add_to_cart', but still the same error.

Comment: dont do the ajax setup and try to include the csrf_token inside the ajax call. The one in my answer

Comment: removed ajax setup and using your code as you suggested but no success.I have just checked cookies section in google chrome and i have seen that first call is including token but second call have no token .Have a look at these screenshots 1:-https://www.screencast.com/t/2ILsMlDCZ9i
2:-https://www.screencast.com/t/mbQLfYLCjRN

Comment: if you could share the code fully on codeshare can have a better look

Comment: @Naveen Kumar Thanks alot sir for your great effort. I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: './add_to_cart',
   headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
   data: {"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",id:prod_id,name: name,price:price},
   success: function( msg ) {

   }
});
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: Thanks guys for your help,I have tried all the provided solutions but the problem is not solving

@Naveen Kumar i have tried your code the token is generating but the response giving the token mismatch exception
Have a look at the chrome console screenshot of AJAX request
https://www.screencast.com/t/gntfBMuhlLf

Comment: your solution is not assigning value to token 
Kindly have a look at the screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/ptnBaziuruZ

Answer (score -1):

If you access the page where you send the data with the url "http://localhost:8000/"
Change the url you are using to make the request to "http://localhost:8000/"

The base url in the address bar and that which you are using to make the request should be the same. The idea is that the domain that is making the request must be the same as the domain of the website making the request. Research on CSRF attacks